# In SPIN/Promela, how to receive a MSG from a channel in the correct way?

Tags: spin, promela

I read the spin guide yet there is no answer for the following question:

I have a line in my code as following:

```
Ch?x
```

where Ch is a channel and x is channel type (to receive MSG)
What happens if Ch is empty? will it wait for MSG to arrive or not?
Do i need to check first if Ch is not empty?

basically all I want is that if Ch is empty then wait till MSG arrives and when it's arrive continue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the current `proctype` will block until a message arrives on `Ch`.  This behavior is described in the [Promela Manual](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/promela.html) under the `receive` statement.  [Because you are providing a variable `x` (as in `Ch?x`) any message in `Ch` will cause the statement to be executable.  That is, the pattern matching aspect of `receive` does not apply.]

Answer (score 2):

Bottom line: the semantics of Promela guarantee your desired behaviour, namely, that the receive-operation blocks until a message can be received.

From the [receive man page](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/receive.html)

> EXECUTABILITY
>   The first and the third form of the statement, written with a single
>   question mark, are executable if the first message in the channel
>   matches the pattern from the receive statement.

This tells you when a receive-operation is *executable*.

The [semantics of Promela](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/Intro.html) then tells you why executability matters:

> As long as there are executable transitions (corresponding to the
>   basic statements of Promela), the semantics engine will select one of
>   them at random and execute it.

Granted, the quote doesn't make it very explicit, but it means that a statement that is currently not executable will block the executing process until it becomes executable.

Here is a small program that demonstrates the behaviour of the receive-operation.

```
chan ch = [1] of {byte};
  /* Must be a buffered channel. A non-buffered, i.e., rendezvous channel,
   * won't work, because it won't be possible to execute the atomic block
   * around ch ! 0 atomically since sending over a rendezvous channel blocks
   * as well.
   */

short n = -1;

proctype sender() {
  atomic  {
    ch ! 0;
    n = n + 1;
  }
}

proctype receiver() {
  atomic  {
    ch ? 0;
    n = -n;
  }
}

init {
  atomic {
    run sender();
    run receiver();
  }

  _nr_pr == 1;

  assert n == 0;
    /* Only true if both processes are executed and if sending happened
     * before receiving.
     */
}
```